# Why the DB data value is blank for fetch_both in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my project, I have some problem in DB

With FETCH_NUM method, it works OK, the content code is:

```
$nodeName=$_POST['nodeInfo'];
include("DB.php");
$data=array();
$sql="select * from GGtable where node='$nodeName';";
$sR=$conn->query($sql);
$rN=$sR->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

//while($rowSV=$sR->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
//  $data[]=$rowSV;
//}

echo '
 <table>
  <tr><td>'.$rN[0].'</td></tr>
 </table>
'
```

But when i try fetch_both method, it works fail. the code is:

```
 $nodeName=$_POST['nodeInfo'];
include("DB.php");
$data=array();
$sql="select * from GGtable where node='$nodeName';";
$sR=$conn->query($sql);

while($rowSV=$sR->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
  $data[]=$rowSV;
}

echo '
 <table>
  <tr><td>'.$data["node"].'</td></tr>
 </table>
'
```

$data["node"] is blank, nothing.

it seems nothing wrong, who can help me ?

Comment: You're trying to expand a variable in a single-quoted string, but PHP won't do that. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing I'm not sure how your first example worked, since it also uses single-quoted strings. Are you sure you're sharing the code you're testing?

Comment: For debugging, I suggest you `print_r($row)` to make sure it's got both string keys and numeric keys, and they're spelled as you expect. Remember PHP associative arrays are case-sensitive, so if the column is named NODE, you can't access it like `$node["node"]`. You're using `select *` in your query, so there's no way we can know if your table even has that column.

Comment: I made mistake, sorry. I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that with this statement:

```
$data[]=$rowSV;
```

you are creating an array of arrays. Thus to access the value of the node column, you actually need to use

```
<tr><td>'.$data[0]["node"].'</td></tr>
```

or replace `0` with whichever row of data you wish to access.

If you only have one row, just replace `$data[]=$rowSV;` with `$data=$rowSV;` and your existing output code will work fine.